# Java Reflections. IDE says it requires to be cast to java.lang.Class but once it is it throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception, bukkit

I recently begun coding some Reflections and I'm encountering this problem when I'm getting a class. Basically title says it all: My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) says a class I'm creating like this:
Class myClass = aMethod.invoke(anObject);
has to be (obviously) cast to Class. As soon as I did it and started, it threw a ClassCastException saying that the actual class it got through the method can't be cast to java.lang.Class.
Edit: I'm coding on Bukkit to make a Minecraft server plugin and I'm attempting to access NMS (Net Minecraft Server), a more internal API which is version based but which can be got for whatever of them through reflections (unless you wanna make it to be singularly for one version).
Here is some more code:

```js
static void setName(Player player, String name) {
        try {
            Method getHandle = player.getClass().getMethod("getHandle");
        Object entityPlayer = getHandle.invoke(player);
        Field bS = entityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredField("bS");
        Object gameProfile = bS.get(entityPlayer);
        Field nameField = gameProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
        nameField.set(gameProfile, name);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find method: ", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find class: ", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not access reflection: ", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not invoke method: ", e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find field: ", e);
        }
    }
```

Now you can see I invoke getHandle method on a player object which, as I've directly specified it, isn't version based, the method though actually belongs a class called CraftPlayer which, although isn't part of nms, is version based too. Also, you may see some attempt you might find senseless through the code.
Error is basically this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.EntityPlayer cannot be cast to java.lang.Cl
```

Edit: I've done some more test today around it and changed many parts of the code, this time the error is that whenever my setName method is called a NoSuchFieldException is caught on field "bS", and I'm COMPLETELY sure it exists. Basically that field is actually on another class called EntityHuman but EntityPlayer class extends it. How could I get the entityPlayer object to be casted to the EntityHuman? Firstly, this class (EntityHuman) is part of NMS too, so since it is version based I will use reflections to attempt accessing it too. I may access it through Class.forName method but I wouldn't know what to properly do even with that. Here below is my current code:

```js
static void setName(Player player, String name) {
  try {
    Method getHandle = player.getClass().getMethod("getHandle");
    Object entityPlayer = getHandle.invoke(player);
    Field bS = entityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredField("bS");
    Object gameProfile = bS.get(entityPlayer);
    Field nameField = gameProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
    nameField.set(gameProfile, name);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find method: ", e);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not access reflection: ", e);
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not invoke method: ", e);
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Main.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not find field: ", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, is the method you are invoking supposed to return a `Class` object? Can you [edit] the question and provide some code including the actual class, instance and method you are invoking?

Comment: I did it.. Perhaps you've not been notified.

Comment: Don't post paraphrases of error messages. Post the entire message.

Comment: Did this one too. I've shown the thrown exception when I perform the command which triggers that method too. Other stuff the console was showing is always shown when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Was the `.getClass` originally there at the method invocation when you got the error?

Comment: I don't remember but I think not, is that a kind of correction it does automatically?

Comment: Is anybody there?

Answer (score 1):

`Method.invoke(Object)` returns `Object`. You should cast it to whatever type the reflected method returns. If your IDE is leading you astray, either ignore it or file a bug report with IDEA. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: I can't specify it directly because doing would make it version based (the actual classes packages contain it).